# Dimplejs Bug. Line does not show up when series is not null

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

I have setup a dimplejs.org line chart.  I should be able to get the the Clicks to be colourized from blue to red (less clicks and the line is blue, more clicks and the line uses a gradient from blue to red).

If I set the series like the following it works fine; however the tooltip only includes the x and y points (Week and Clicks).  I need the tooltip to include the Month.

```
var mySeries = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
```

If I modify the series (as per other examples on dimplejs.org and as shown below) to include all fields in the array, the line disappears and I get a gradient error in the console.

```
var mySeries = myChart.addSeries(["Month","Week","Clicks"],dimple.plot.line);
```

I have tried this for the tooltip; but it doesn't help:

```
mySeries.getTooltipText = function (e) {
                return [
                    "Month: " + e.aggField[0],
                    "Week in the year: " + e.aggField[1],
                    "Clicks in the week: " + e.aggField[2]
                ];
            };
```

I have created this fiddle with the bug/issue.  Can someone show me how to get the colourized lines to show up and without the console error. Hope you can help.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eformx/beL2bwa3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There do seem to be some issues with the gradient line, it only works in simple cases.  I don't think it can realistically be made to work across the different axis types so I will probably remove the feature from future releases.  The logic depends on a category vs measure axis.  If that can be made to suit your case then you can achieve what you want.

The data in the fiddle you link to doesn't seem to quite match your question but you could achieve something like what you describe as follows.  Due to the limitations of the gradient line you need to use a measure axis and a category axis then put the data in using a custom tooltip method:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);

var data = [
    { "Month" : "Jan", "Week" : "2014-01-20", "Clicks" : "10"},
    { "Month" : "Jan", "Week" : "2014-01-27", "Clicks" : "4"},
    { "Month" : "Feb", "Week" : "2014-02-03", "Clicks" : "35"},
    { "Month" : "Feb", "Week" : "2014-02-10", "Clicks" : "46"},
    { "Month" : "Feb", "Week" : "2014-02-17", "Clicks" : "34"},
    { "Month" : "Feb", "Week" : "2014-02-24", "Clicks" : "26"},
    { "Month" : "Mar", "Week" : "2014-03-03", "Clicks" : "12"}
];

var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);

chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Week");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Clicks");
chart.addColorAxis("Clicks", ["blue", "red"]);
var s = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);

s.getTooltipText = function(e) {
    var i,
        row;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
        row = data[i];
        if (row.Week === e.xField[0]) {
            return [
                "Month: " + row.Month,
                "Week in the year: " + row.Week,
                "Clicks in the week: " + e.yValue
            ];
        }
    }
};

s.lineWeight = 5;
s.lineMarkers = true;

chart.draw();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/beL2bwa3/3/

Comment: Thanks John! Works great!  Love the charting library!

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler workaround where you can call the `addseries()` twice, once with the array of fields including tool tip fields and real field, and the second time with just the real category field. The order of calling is important to get both the line and the extra tool tips:

```
myChart.addSeries("Sex", dimple.plot.line);

myChart.addSeries(["Count Survived","Group Count","Sex"], dimple.plot.line)
```